# Set one third-party JAR's classpath to include another one with Ant

Tags: java, ant, classpath

How can I set the classpath of one third-party JAR to include a second third-party JAR in Ant?

I need this to run the vanilla *Using Schematron with ANT* example from [this site](http://schematron.com/implementation.html). <sup>(I'm 99% sure you don't need to know what Schematron is to answer this question.)</sup> The example's instructions are in a short PDF linked near the top of the page. I copy-pasted the contents of all the files directly from the PDF into Eclipse.

I then downloaded `ant-schematron-2010-04-14.jar` from the above site, and got `saxon9he.jar` from the SAXON SourceForge page. I also changed the buildfile to match. With line numbers and without comments, it looks like this:

```
09 <project name="schematron-ant-sample" default="validate">
14     <taskdef name="schematron"
15              classname="com.schematron.ant.SchematronTask"
16              classpath="lib/ant-schematron-2010-04-14.jar; lib/saxon9he.jar" />
22     <target name="validate" description="Test with a Fileset">
23         <schematron schema="sch/sample.sch" failonerror="false">
24             <fileset dir="xml" includes="*.xml" />
25         </schematron>
26     </target>
27 </project>
```

When I ran the buildfile, I got the following error:

```
validate:

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\gdawes\Documents\workspace\SchematronAntExample\build.xml:23: /
javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError: Provider /
net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl not found

Total time: 265 milliseconds
```

A similar error occurs if the SAXON JAR isn't listed in `schematron`'s classpath. I've confirmed that `TransformerFactoryImpl` is present in the SAXON JAR, but I can't figure out how to get the Schematron code to recognize it. How should I set up the classpath? (Or, if I'm wrong and this isn't a classpath issue, how do I get the build to succeed?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `classpath` in the `<taskdef>` should only contain: `lib/ant-schematron-2010-04-14.jar`, similar to the example provided in ***[Using Schematron for Ant by example](http://schematron.com/resource/Using_Schematron_for_Ant.pdf)***.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="schematron-ant-sample" default="validate">
  <taskdef name="schematron"
      classname="com.schematron.ant.SchematronTask"
      classpath="lib/ant-schematron-2010-04-14.jar" />
  <target name="validate" description="Test with a Fileset">
    <schematron schema="sch/sample.sch" failonerror="false">
      <fileset dir="xml" includes="*.xml" />
    </schematron>
  </target>
</project>
```

In addition to correcting the `<taskdef>`, placing the `saxon9he.jar` in the Ant library folder makes `net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl` available and resolves the error (tested on Ubuntu Linux with Ant 1.8.2).

Comment: @LordTorgamus, answer updated with note about placing `saxon9he.jar` in the Ant library folder so that `net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl` is available.

Comment: @LordTorgamus, in addition, the PDF ***[Using Schematron for Ant by example](http://schematron.com/resource/Using_Schematron_for_Ant.pdf)*** provides an example indicating that the `<taskdef>` should only contain the path to the `ant-schematron` jar file.

Comment: Are you referring to `{ANT_HOME}\lib`?

Comment: I am aware of that, and that is why it was the first thing I tried. I did mention in the question body that it didn't work. The difference is that it was a `NoClassDefFoundError`, not a `TransformerFactoryConfigurationError`. I'll add that to the question if I end up editing it again (doesn't seem important enough on its own).

Comment: Regarding the Ant library location, that is correct `{ANT_HOME}\lib`. In Ant, you can print Ant home with: `<echo message="${ant.home}" />`

Comment: I went ahead and just tried it. Oddly, although the build still fails from within Eclipse, it succeeds when run from the command line. I did restart Eclipse. I wonder if it uses a separate installation of Ant.

Comment: I think Ant picks up entries in its ${ant.home}/lib directory automatically, while Eclipse waits for you to add them using the `Classpath` tab of the `External Tools Configuration` window.

Comment: @davidfmatheson Aha! My Classpath tab (reached via Run > External Tools > External Tools Configurations) shows that Eclipse thinks `ANT_HOME` means the contents of `C:\Users\gdawes\MyEclipse\Common\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.7.1\lib`. Adding the SAXON JAR to that location makes things work in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, the classpath on a taskdef is just the classpath used to look up the class that you're trying to load, it is not the classpath that the task actually runs with.  Try adding the required jars to the `User Entries` section of the `Classpath` tab of the Ant build configuration in Eclipse.

Comment: This did it. Putting the SAXON JAR in the `taskdef`'s classpath is unnecessary, though harmless. For future reference, the Classpath tab can be reached by right-clicking on the buildfile and selecting "Run As > External Tools Configuration..." or Run > External Tools > External Tools Configurations